# Extract values after pattern in Ruby string

Tags: ruby, string

I have a string like this:

`"<root><some ProdCode=\"40\" ProducerName=\"demo1\" ProdCode=\"40\" Need_Confirmation=\"1\"/><some ProdCode=\"40\" ProducerName=\"demo1\" ProdCode=\"40\" Need_Confirmation=\"1\"/></root>"`

I'm trying to pull the content from this string which is between =\"*content*\" and put it in an array, like ["40","demo1","40","1",40......]

Comment: What you have so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `:scan` to select elements by regexp pattern. Then remove escape characters.

```
string.scan(/"[^"]+"/).map { |element| element.delete('\\"')  }
```

**Explanation of pattern:**

1. `/` – regexp starts
2. `"` – first char should be `"`
3. `[^"]+` – next should be any char except `"`. + sign says that number of such chars should be at least 1.
4. `"` – next should be again `"`
5. `/` – regexp ends

So `string.scan(/"[^"]+"/)` would return:

```
["\"40\"", "\"demo1\"", "\"40\"", "\"1\"", "\"40\"", "\"demo1\"", "\"40\"", "\"1\""]
```

Then we can just delete `\"` using `:delete` method.

Convenient tool to build regexps is http://rubular.com/

Comment: when content is blank i.e "\" then regex is breaking and giving invalid result.

Comment: You can simplify by putting`[^]+` in a capture group: `string.scan(/"([^"]+)"/).flatten`.

Comment: You can handle empty values like this: `string.gsub(/""/, '" "').scan(/"[^"]+"/).map { |element| element.delete('\\"')  }`

Answer (score 0):

When your string is this simple you can use scan + regular expression like this:

result = html.scan(/ProdCode="\d+?"/)

If it is more complex you can use a html parser like nokogiri or oga.

Comment: i used nokogiri to parse but since data is huge getting memory allocation error.

Comment: In this case you can try to use nokigiris facility to parse a stream instead of loading the whole xml file, if it is possible.